# Помогите определить код для ответа

Tags: http, rest

В REST, при попытке **удалить** ресурс, который уже **был удалён**, какой код следует возвращать?

P.S.: я вообще колеблюсь между `404` и `410`

Comment: наверно можно самому определить коды для ошибок и не мучиться. вот взять что-то за основу от vk к примеру https://vk.com/dev/errors ....

Comment: @АлексейШиманский меня интересуют именно конвенции REST. За неимением таких, конвенции RoR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще, суть REST в идемпотентности. Посмотрите [спецификацию](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html). По идеи не важно, был ли удалён раннее уже или нет.

Из книги [RESTful Web Services Cookbook: Solutions for Improving Scalability and Simplicity](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=LDuzpQlVuG4C&dq=RESTful%20Web%20Services%20Cookbook:%20Solutions%20for%20Improving%20Scalability%20an&hl=ru&source=gbs_navlinks_s):

> The DELETE method is idempotent. This implies that the server must
>   return response code 200 (OK) even if the server deleted the resource
>   in a previous request. But in practice, implementing DELETE as an
>   idempotent operation requires the server to keep track of all deleted
>   resources. Otherwise, it can return a 404 (Not Found).

Так что, рекомендуется возвращать код 200. Но, в некоторых кейсах можно и 404 возвращать.